# SVN URL non-existent in that revision Error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Im getting an Error that is in my Tourtouse SVN Repository...

The Error is "URL non-existent in revision"

I just reformatted my computer that contained all the source code.  On that machine is another harddrive that contains all my source code.  I didn't reformat that hard drive.

Now When I try to connect to that repository from another machine (laptop) I get this error when opening up the repository or trying to commit or even update.  I don't know much about SVN so I don't know how it works so I can fix this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the wrong URL being used as my repository...